# multiple replaces with javascript

Tags: javascript, replace

In PHP, you do this to replace more then one value at a time.

```
<?php
$string = "i am the foobar";

$newstring = str_replace(array('i', 'the'), array('you', 'a'), $string);

echo $newstring;
?>
```

How do you do this in javascript?

Comment: There are better answers in another question on Stackoverflow. In my opinion the best answers are [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Use javascript's [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method, stringing multiple replace's together. ie:

```
var somestring = "foo is an awesome foo bar foo foo"; //somestring lowercase
var replaced = somestring.replace(/foo/g, "bar").replace(/is/g, "or");
// replaced now contains: "bar or an awesome bar bar bar bar"
```

Comment: Excellent just what I was looking for...I was dealing with dynamic strings so mine ended up looking something like var exp = new RegExp(foo, 'g'); somestring.replace(exp, 'bar');

Comment: Awesome very good solution.

Comment: I want to replace several strings with one string. Like a->'', b->'',etc. Is there a better way than concatenate replace(s)?

Answer (score 16):

You could do:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugKRr/

```
var string = "jak har en mamma";

string = string.replace(/(jak)|(mamma)/g,function(str,p1,p2) {
        if(p1) return 'du';
        if(p2) return 'pappa';
    });
```

or:

http://jsfiddle.net/ugKRr/2/

```
var string = "jak har en mamma";

string = string.replace(/jak/g,'du').replace(/mamma/g,'pappa');
```