# Replacing ${...} in javascript string?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, str-replace

How do you replace all instances of ${...} in a javascript string? Example:

```
var before = "My name is ${name} and I like ${sport} because ${sport} is challenging."
```

becomes

```
var after = "My name is Bob and I like soccer because soccer is challenging."
```

I tried following the best answer from [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings), but you cannot have a key that starts with a symbol...

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying the answer from the question you linked, you can [capture](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) part of the match (only the name) and use that as the key:

```
var str = "My name is ${name} and I like ${sport} because ${sport} is challenging.";
var mapObj = {
   name:"Bob",
   sport:"soccer"
};
str = str.replace(/[$]{([^{}]+)}/g, function(match, key){
  return mapObj[key];
});
```

The second argument to the anonymous function will be filled with what was matched inside the first pair of parentheses in the pattern (i.e. what was matched by `[^{}]*`).

Of course, you should add some sanity check that your `key` is actually present in the map. Alternatively, use the approach from the other question and just list the allowed names in the pattern:

```
/[$]{(name|sport)}/g
```

Comment: this is wicked genius.

Comment: I really need to brush up on my regular expressions, thanks a ton for the quick and concise answer!

Comment: @user1464011 the tutorial I linked is a really good point to start ;)