# What is the best way to convert **title** to <h1>title</h1> in large text in one string traversal?

Tags: javascript, regex

Suppose there is a large paragraph of text, the conversion rules are:

- `**title**` to `<h1>title</h1>`
- `:blush:` to `<img class="emoji" title="blush" src="/img/blush.png"/>`

How can I do the conversion in one traversal?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @sp00m I tried to look at marked.js, but it is too complex for me to understand...

Comment: This is a good question, doing string or regex replaces in parallel is different from doing them in sequence (think `.replace('+', '-').replace('-', '+')`. I haven't found a well-answered duplicate on SO

Comment: Okay, found one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings It uses the fact that you can give a function as second argument to `.replace`.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do such things is [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) - it is very optimized mechanism for such tasks in every language.

in javascript according to your examples:

```
>>> "**title** qweqwe **foo** ololo **bar**".replace(/(\*\*(\w+)\*\*)/g, "<h1>$2</h1>")
"<h1>title</h1> qweqwe <h1>foo</h1> ololo <h1>bar</h1>"
```

and

```
":blush: qweqwe :tongue: ololo :smile:".replace(/(\:(\w+)\:)/g, '<img class="emoji" title="$2" src:="/img/$2.png"/>')
"<img class="emoji" title="blush" src:="/img/blush.png"/> qweqwe <img class="emoji" title="tongue" src:="/img/tongue.png"/> ololo <img class="emoji" title="smile" src:="/img/smile.png"/>"
```

tada!

Comment: That's two traversals, one for headers and one for emojis.

Comment: well there ARE `x|y` syntax in js regexps but no named groups syntax... so we can not distinguish which is where. Or you can use this crossbrowser js library for extended regexp syntax - http://xregexp.com/syntax/#namedCapture but I'd suggest you to not do that and use only plain one.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this :

```
<div id="replace">**title**some text :blush: some link </div>
var str= $("#replace").html();    
str = str.replace("**title**", "<h1>title</h1>");     
str = str.replace(":blush:", "<img class="emoji" title="blush" src:"/img/blush.png"/>");     
$("#replace").html(str);
```

Comment: Thanks! It certainly is a good start for me!

Answer (score 1):

Capture the different patterns in 1 regex with different capture groups and have a replace-function inspect the different capture groups:

```js
var input = '**Hey** Oh you! :blush:';
document.write(input.replace(/\*\*([^*]*)\*\*|:(happy|blush):/ig, function(match, title, smiley) {
  if (title != undefined) {
    return '<h2>' + title + '</h2>';
  } else if (smiley != undefined) {
    return '<img class="emoji" title="blush" src="/img/' + smiley + '.png" />';
  }
}));
```

This is the only answer with just one traversal on this page. Note though that it won't catch this:

```
var text = '**title with :blush: smiley** gotcha!';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex for this problem.

```
var mystring = 'some text **title** some other text';
var re = /\*{2}(\w*)\*{2}/g;
mystring.replace(re, "<h1>$1</h1>");
```

Here the regex searches for any pattern starting with two * and ending with two *. The middle part is captured and used in the replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Title

```
var re_title = /\*\*(.+)\*\*/g;
str.replace(re_title, '<h1>$1</h1>')
```

Emoji

```
var re_emoji = /:(.+):/g;
str.replace(re_emoji, '<img class="emoji" title="$1" src="/img/$1.png"/>')
```

You can club them together by running one replace after the other.

```
str.replace(re_title, '<h1>$1</h1>').replace(re_emoji, '<img class="emoji" title="$1" src="/img/$1.png"/>')
```

Sample

```
var str = '**title** :some_emoji:'
str.replace(re_title, '<h1>$1</h1>').replace(re_emoji, '<img class="emoji" title="$1" src="/img/$1.png"/>')
// output = "<h1>title</h1> <img class="emoji" title="some_emoji" src="/img/some_emoji.png"/>"

var str = '**:some_emoji: **'
str.replace(re_title, '<h1>$1</h1>').replace(re_emoji, '<img class="emoji" title="$1" src="/img/$1.png"/>')
// output = "<h1><img class="emoji" title="some_emoji" src="/img/some_emoji.png"/></h1>"
```

Since the capture groups cannot be named, the 'a|b' regex syntax cannot be used for replacement.