# Search and replace word of textarea onclick

Tags: jquery, replace

I'm looking for a way to search and replace some word onclick (not all content). It's working only on predefined textarea. I want to run the script for the words I've just wrote.

```
<form action="#">
<textarea class="input" name="input" type="text" id="txt" />test</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="run"/>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#run').click(function() {
    var textarea=$('#txt'); 
    textarea.html(textarea.html().replace(/test/g,"ok")); 
    });
});
```

Comment: Use val() instead of html()

Comment: what text you want to change?? you can use regex...

Comment: Well, If I wrote for example : "Hi, this is a test". this will be replaced by "Hi, this is a ok"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#run').click(function() {
    var textarea=$('#txt'); 
    textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/test/g,"ok")); 
    });
```

Comment: And what about replacing more than one word ? For example : replace "test" by "ok" and "hello" by "bye" ?

Comment: "test hello".replace(/test/g,"ok").replace(/hello/g,"dude")

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings

Comment: One more, thing, do you how to remove the "span" tag in a textarea ? For ex : "<span class="dssdf">test</span>"  become  "test"

Comment: $("textarea span").remove()

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#run').click(function() {
    var textarea=$('#txt'); 
    textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/test/g,"ok")); 
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="input" name="input" type="text" id="txt" />test</textarea>
<input type="button" value="Run" id="run"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/27ty01m1/)

```
  textarea.val(textarea.val().replace(/test/g,"ok"));
```

**html()**

Obtains the HTML content of the first element in the matched set.

**val()**

Returns the value attribute of the first element in the matched set. When the element is a multiselect element, the returned value is an array of all selections. This method only work with control like input, select, button etc. It not work with div, span, p etc.

[Difference of .val() and .html() link here](http://www.jquerywithexample.com/2012/09/difference-between-val-html-and-text-in.html)