# How to replace several different items in a template text document in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I am trying to create a service where an email is sent after an http request is made.  I have several variables defined within the text of the document, something like `#FIRSTNAME` `#LASTNAME` etc. and after an even I want to replace these with information received by the post (i.e. dynamically and not prior known variables).

The current method I am using involved a regex method of

```
matcha = /#FIRSTNAME/
matchb = /#LASTNAME/
```

But after only those two emails I have a pretty long code string that looks like:

```
 let outgoingEmail = data.replace(matcha, vara).replace(matchb, varb)
```

Is there a more concise way to replace several matches or do I have to just chain all of the matches together?

With two I guess this is tolerable but I would like to replace many and I am wondering how things like email templating services typically handle this.

Comment: This looks very similar to [another question that I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings) several years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an object to store the *needles* and their *replacement*. Using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all the keys in the object and [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor, create a regex with OR `|` in the keys.

Then use `String#replace` with function to replace the *needles* by their values from the object.

```
var replacements = {
    '#FIRSTNAME': 'Tushar',
    '#LASTNAME': 'Secret'
    ...
};

var regex = new RegExp(Object.keys(replacements).join('|'), 'g');
// Use `i` flag to match case-insensitively

data.replace(regex, function(m) {
    return replacements[m] || m;
});
```

**Note:** If the string to find contains characters having special meaning in regex, they need to be escaped before creating regex from string.

Comment: This looks great, but I updated my answer, I am looking for a version that can use dynamic variables.  Here `Tushar` and `secret` are hard coded.

Comment: @Startec You can assign the values when creating object. As you've variables, you can use those as values in object.

Comment: don't I have to pass in `replacements` to `Object.keys()`?

Comment: @Startec sorry, my mistake. Thanks for correcting me. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a basic template engine rather easily if you use `.replace` with a callback function, and supply an object with variable names.

### Simple Example:

```js
var data = '\n' +
 'firstname:  #FIRSTNAME\n' +
 'lastname: #LASTNAME\n' +
 '\n';

var replace = {
 FIRSTNAME: 'John',
 LASTNAME: 'Smith'
};

var message = data.replace(/#([A-Z]+)/g, function(all, word) {
 return replace[word];
});

console.log(message);
```

The regex I used will match any `#`'s followed by all-capital-letters. You can adjust it to your needs.