# How to replace 2 strings with one sting javascript

Tags: javascript, string

i Have a string in that sometimes **?** sometimes � will come i want to replace it with single quotation.

i want some thing like this:

```
var Option = Option.replace("?"|"�", "'");
```

> But this code is not working how can i write string replace in javascript.?

Comment: If your question is how to do this in JavaScript, don't spam the PHP tags [tag:php] and [tag:str-replace].

Comment: Use the global regex flag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use a regular expression with a character class:

```
option = option.replace(/[?�]/g, "'");
```

```js
var option = "Testing? Testing� Testing";
option = option.replace(/[?�]/g, "'");
console.log(option);
```

I added the `g` flag on the theory you probably don't want to replace just the first one. If you *do* want to replace just the first one, remove the `g` flag.

Comment: There **has** to be a dupetarget for this. *Edit:* Yup.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings) or ...

Comment: It worked thankx for your time.. Actually it is a utf 8 issue im not able to fix that so im doing in this way. is it a correct way..?

Comment: @evolutionxbox: That one's much more complicated, but I found one. :-)

Comment: Can you tell me this in php @T.J.Crowder i want this in php as well

Comment: @AbdulWaheed: It's conceptually identical, just look up how to use `preg_replace`.