# What's the best way to search and replace all for multiple terms?

Tags: d

I have a naive function implemented to remove HTML entities. But this will do a full string search for each entity. What is the best way to do a multi string search and replace?

```
string replace_entities(ref string x){
  return sanitize(x).replace("&#8217;","'").replace("&#8216;","'").replace("&apos;","'").replace("&#8211;","-").replace("&#8212;","-")
    .replace("&#8220;","\"").replace("&#8221;","\"").replace("&#8221;","\"").replace("&#39;","'")
    .replace("&amp;", "&").replace("&ndash","-").replace("&mdash","-").replace("&quot;", "\"").strip();
}
```

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings) out, I guess it will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with Regex.
I made a full example focus on performance :)

```
import std.stdio : writeln;
import std.algorithm : reduce, find;
import std.regex : ctRegex, Captures, replaceAll;   

/*
Compile time conversion table:
["from", "to"]
*/
enum HTMLEntityTable = [
    ["&#8217;"  ,"'"  ],
    ["&#8216;"  ,"'"  ],
    ["&apos;"   ,"'"  ],
    ["&#8211;"  ,"-"  ],
    ["&#8212;"  ,"-"  ],
    ["&#8220;"  ,"\"" ],
    ["&#8221;"  ,"\"" ],
    ["&#8221;"  ,"\"" ],
    ["&#39;"    ,"'"  ],
    ["&amp;"    ,"&"  ],
    ["&ndash"   ,"-"  ],
    ["&mdash"   ,"-"  ],
    ["&quot;"   ,"\"" ]
];

/*
Compile time Regex String:
Use reduce to concatenate HTMLEntityTable on index 1 to form "&#8217;|&#8216;|..."
*/
enum regex_replace = ctRegex!( 
    reduce!((a, b)=>a~"|"~b[0])(HTMLEntityTable[0][0],HTMLEntityTable[1..$]) 
);

/*
Replace Function:
Find matched string on HTMLEntityTable and replace it.
(Maybe I should use my HTMLEntityTable as a Associative Array
 but I think this way is faster ) 
*/
auto HTMLReplace(Captures!string str){      
    return HTMLEntityTable.find!(a=>a[0] == str.hit)[0][1];
}

//User Function.
auto replace_entities( ref string html ){   
    return replaceAll!HTMLReplace( html, regex_replace);
}

void main(){
    auto html = "Start&#8217;&#8216;&apos;&#8211;&#8212;&#8220;&#8221;&#8221;&#39;&amp;&ndash&mdash&quot;End";
    replace_entities( html ).writeln;
    //Output:
    //Start'''--"""'&--"End
}
```