# Replace all occurrence of specific words in a sentence based on an array of words

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Ive an array like this

```
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"];
```

So the Im trying to make a function or any quick way to remove the occurances of the above words from a sentence. Not using any looping how can I quickly achieve that.

They way Im doing it now

```js
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"];
var sentence = "The first solution does not work for any UTF-8 alphaben. (It will cut text such as Привіт). I have managed to create function which do not use RegExp and use good UTF-8 support in JavaScript engine. The idea is simple if symbol is equal in uppercase and lowercase it is special character. The only exception is made for whitespace.";

$(excludeWords).each(function(index, item) {
  var s = new RegExp(item, "gi");
  sentence = sentence.replace(s, "");
});
alert(sentence);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But is there is any better solution than looping??

**Based on a comment little more details..**

It never should remove part of a word. it should only replace a full word

Comment: use JS map function

Comment: you have _'any'_ it sentence that became _'ny'_ and don't match _'ANY'_. Is it on prupuse?

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/15604206/1719752

Comment: @DragandDrop Oh.. no it shouldnt happen.. I didnt noticed it.. It should consider words only.. I will mention it in the question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're almost there. The trick is to combine all words into one big regexp to do the replacement just once. `\\b`'s ensure that you actually replacing whole words and not just substrings.

```js
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"];

var sentence = "The first solution does not work for any UTF-8 alphaben. (It will cut text such as Привіт). I have managed to create function which do not use RegExp and use good UTF-8 support in JavaScript engine. The idea is simple if symbol is equal in uppercase and lowercase it is special character. The only exception is made for whitespace.";

var re = new RegExp(`\\b(${excludeWords.join('|')})\\b`, 'gi');
sentence = sentence.replace(re, "");
console.log(sentence);
```

Note that this eventually creates consecutive spaces in the string. These can be easily removed with `replace(/\s+/g, ' ').trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd split on space, and just check if the word is in the array in a filter

```js
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"];

var sentence = "The first solution does not work for any UTF-8 alphaben. (It will cut text such as Привіт). I have managed to create function which do not use RegExp and use good UTF-8 support in JavaScript engine. The idea is simple if symbol is equal in uppercase and lowercase it is special character. The only exception is made for whitespace.";

var res = sentence.split(" ").filter(w=>!excludeWords.includes(w.toUpperCase())).join(" ");

console.log(res)
```

If you simply replace strings with a regex, you'll have some issues, for instance `solution` ends up being `luti` as both `so` and `on` are in the array, so you need to compare complete words instead

Answer (score 1):

You can make one string of the array values and then apply regex on it and again convert it to array.

```
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"];

var array_to_string = excludeWords.join(' ');
var s = new RegExp(array_to_string, "gi");
var sentence = sentence.replace(s, "");
var excludewords_updated = sentence.split(' ');
```

so this is how you can do it without looping.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a word boundary `\b` for getting only words to replace.

```js
var excludeWords = ["A", "ABOUT", "ABOVE", "ACROSS", "ALL", "ALONG", "AM", "AN", "AND", "ANY", "ASK", "AT", "AWAY", "CAN", "DID", "DIDN'T", "DO", "DON'T", "FOR", "FROM", "HAD", "HAS", "HER", "HIS", "IN", "INTO", "IS", "IT", "NONE", "NOT", "OF", "ON", "One", "OUT", "SO", "SOME", "THAT", "THE", "THEIR", "THERE", "THEY", "THESE", "THIS", "TO", "TWIT", "WAS", "WERE", "WEREN'T", "WHICH", "WILL", "WITH", "WHAT", "WHEN", "WHY"],
    sentence = "The first solution does not work for any UTF-8 alphaben. (It will cut text such as Привіт). I have managed to create function which do not use RegExp and use good UTF-8 support in JavaScript engine. The idea is simple if symbol is equal in uppercase and lowercase it is special character. The only exception is made for whitespace.";

sentence  = excludeWords.reduce(function(r, s) {
    return r.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + s + '\\b', "gi"), "");
}, sentence);

console.log(sentence);
```

Answer (score 1):

will be better if we split on the basis of word boundaries.

```
sentence = sentence.split(/\b/).reduce((str, word) => {
  return new Set(excludeWords).has(word)
    ? str + word.replace(/./g, '')
    : str + word;
}, '').replace(/\s\s+/,' ').trim();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `preg_replace_all("~[\"](.*)[\"]~isuU", $data, $found)`