# Way to replace substring that in regular expression with another

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to know way to replace substring in url with new string.

> https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DW7hPt9VAAAdKE7?format=jpg&name=small
>   after "&name=" they are many kind of size like
>   900x900,medium,360x360,small

```
let href = document.location.href;
if(!href.includes('&name=orig')){
    if(href.includes(/900x900|medium|360x360|small/){ //if href have some size in regular expression
    // I try to make it search for substring in regular expression
        document.location.href = href.replace(/900x900|medium|360x360|small/,'orig');
    }
    else{ //if url don't have '&name=' like above
        var adding = '&name=orig';
        document.location.href = link+adding;
    }
}
```

It not working 
I don't want to write code to check all case like

```
if(href.includes('900x900')
if(href.includes('medium')
if(href.includes('360x360')
if(href.includes('small')
```

they are way to find match at once?

Comment: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings>

Comment: Can you put your original string for the url? https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DW7hPt9VAAAdKE7?format=jpg&name=small900X900 or https://pbs.twimg.com/media/DW7hPt9VAAAdKE7?format=jpg&name=small&size=900X900?

Comment: replace small with 900x900,medium,360x360

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change if(href.includes(/900x900|medium|360x360|small/){ to

```
if(href.search(/900x900|medium|360x360|small/) !== -1){
```

as includes accepts the string not the regex.