# regex for replace words inside text by another words

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text string i want to replace it by another text using regexp

Means each word replaced with a specific word

```
input= Jounal Page Year DOI Roche-Link
```

my expected output

```
output = Publication Title Pagination Publication Date Digital Object Identifier Roche Link
```

Journal replace by Publication Title

Page replace by Pagination

Year replace by Publication Date

DOI replace byDigital Object Identifier

Roche-Link replace by Roche Link

- my regex=\b(Journal|Year|Page|DOI|Roche-Link)\b

my regexp Detect all the specific words but I didn't find a solution using `$` to replace each word the with the specific word

```
output = input.replace(/\b(Journal|Year|Page|DOI|Roche-Link)\b/g, (Publication Title)+$1, (Pagination)+$2,(Publication Date)+$3,(Digital Object Identifier)+$4,(Roche Link)+$5)
```

Comment: Regular Expressions vary slightly from language to language. When asking for regex make sure to add the language tag aswell.

Comment: Is this similar? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings

Comment: I'm looking for a solution using $ to replace each word  with specific word

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```js
var dict = {
  "Journal": "Publication Title",
  "Page":  "Pagination",
  "Year":  "Publication Date",
  "DOI": "Digital Object Identifier",
  "Roche-Link":  "Roche Link"
};

var regExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + Object.keys(dict).join("|") + ")\\b", "g");

var translated = "Journal Page Year DOI Roche-Link".replace(regExp, function(match) {
  return dict[match];
});

console.log(translated);
```

Comment: thanks ! but I'm looking for a solution using `$` to replace each word  with specific word