# replace text to variable's value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, regex

I have created a function to get `sms message` from db using `ajax get call` and after success i want to replace the `{order_id}` text to order-id like `454574` and may b few more variables like customer name etc.

**MY TRY**

```
$(document).delegate('.sms-template', 'click', function() {
  var tempID = $(this).attr('id').replace('sms-template-','');
  var oID = $(this).attr('data-id').replace('sms-template-','');

  $.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=sale/order/getSmsTemplate&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&template_id='+tempID, 
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'json',          
    success: function(json) {

        $('textarea#input-order-comment-'+oID).append(json['message']);
    },
    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
    }
  });
});
```

It works fine and display `message` in `textarea` as

```
Dear {customer_name}, Your Order : {order_id} is successfully placed and ready to process.
```

i want to replace {customer_name} & {order_id} with its number which i have stored in php variable.

PS: I don't have much knowledge of RegEx.

Comment: What about a simple replace, e.g. `"You order Id: {order_id} is handover to courier.".replace("{order_id}","454574")`

Comment: i need it dynamically... 1 script for every order

Comment: Of course, posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest here would most likely be a `replace()`

```
string.replace("old value","new value")
```

E.g.

```
var the_id = "454574";   // or where you get that from
var new_message = json['message'].replace("{order_id}",the_id);

$('textarea#input-order-comment-'+oID).append(new_message);
```

---

Updated based on a comment and question edit

To replace additional info, one could do something like this

```
var the_id = "Order id", the_name = "Customer name";
var new_message = json['message'].replace("{order_id}",the_id).replace("{customer_name}", the_name);

$('textarea#input-order-comment-'+oID).append(new_message);
```

---

If there will many more replacements, here is a post that have some clever solutions:

- [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings)

Comment: what if i want to replace two things, order_id and customer_name ...then?

Comment: @MoizAhmad As there is no info about those in the question, I really can't say. Maybe if you show how `json` looks like, and assuming those info are in there...?

Comment: if message is like , Dear {customer_name}, Your Order : {order_id} is successfully placed and ready to process.

Comment: then how can i change with variable using your script?

Comment: @MoizAhmad Updated my answer with a 2nd sample

Comment: @MoizAhmad Great...also added a link to another post, showing some more clever solution if you need to do more, multiple replacements.