# Use just one method many times in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a script to replace content of a document:

```
var mytitle = document.title ;
document.title = mytitle
  .replace(/old1/gi, "new1")
  .replace(/old2/gi, "new2")
  .replace(/old3/gi, "new3")
  .replace(/old4/gi, "new4")
  .replace(/old5/gi, "new5"); 
var mybody=document.body.innerHTML ;
document.body.innerHTML=mybody
  .replace(/old1/gi, "new1")
  .replace(/old2/gi, "new2")
  .replace(/old3/gi, "new3")
  .replace(/old4/gi, "new4")
  .replace(/old5/gi, "new5");
```

You can see i must write `replace(/old1/gi, "new1").replace(/old2/gi, "new2").replace(/old3/gi, "new3").replace(/old4/gi, "new4").replace(/old5/gi, "new5");`  2 times.

How to make script works even just write above code once? like this:

```
var myreplace=replace(/old1/gi, "new1").replace(/old2/gi, "new2").replace(/old3/gi, "new3").replace(/old4/gi, "new4").replace(/old5/gi, "new5");
var mytitle = document.title ;
document.title = mytitle.myreplace;
var mybody=document.body.innerHTML ;
document.body.innerHTML=mybody.myreplace
```

Notice: `old1`,`new1`... are strings.

Comment: post the title please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question basically you need to write once. You can simply do so by writing those steps into a function and calling that function.

```
var titleEditor = function(toEdit) {
    return toEdit.replace(/old1/gi, "new1")
                 .replace(/old2/gi, "new2")
                 .replace(/old3/gi, "new3")
                 .replace(/old4/gi, "new4")
                 .replace(/old5/gi, "new5");
    } 
    var mytitle = document.title ; 
    document.title = titleEditor(mytitle)
    var mybody=document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML= titleEditor(mybody);
```

Now if you titleEditor functionality is same as old1, old2 then you can write titleEditor as @CertainPermormance described

```
var titleEditor = function(toEdit){
     return toEdit.replace(/old(\d)/gi, 'new$1')
    }
```

One more way you can do is adding method to String prototype

```
String.prototype.updateTitle = function(){
  return this.replace(/old(\d)/gi, 'new$1');
}
var mytitle = document.title ; 
document.title = mytitle.updateTitle()
var mybody=document.body.innerHTML;
document.body.innerHTML= mybody.updateTitle();
```

Hope it's helpful

Comment: Mutating the built-in objects and prototypes is *very* bad practice -  you should always prefer using standalone functions instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can match `old`, with lookahead for a number, and replace that with `new`:

```js
const str = 'foo foo old1 bar bar old2 baz baz baz old3';
console.log(
  str.replace(/old(?=\d)/gi, 'new')
);
```

Comment: No, 'old1', 'old2'... is a string

Comment: What do you mean? The `/old#/gi`s are regular expressions in your code, not strings, this should work as well

Comment: I mean, it's similiar `replace(/abc-(.*?)/gi, 'abc $1').replace(/def\nd/gi, 'defd')`...

Comment: @Arulraj Oops, you're right (plus lookahead for the digit), thanks

Comment: Thank all you guys, @Nilesh Soni helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that takes string argument and return modified string. 

    `function replaceContent(string) {
        if (!string) return;
        return string
         .replace(/old1/gi, "new1")
         .replace(/old2/gi, "new2")
         .replace(/old3/gi, "new3")
         .replace(/old4/gi, "new4")
         .replace(/old5/gi, "new5"); 
    }`

Comment: Thank for your suggest!