# Replace all variables in string using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Using a combination of a couple of previous answers I've tried to put together a RegEx that'll allow me to replace all occurrences of anything within curly braces

I got this far, but it doesn't seem to work

```
var str = "The {type} went to the {place}";


var mapObj = {
   type: 'Man',
   place: "Shop"

};
var re = new RegExp(/(?<=\{)Object.keys(mapObj).join("|")(?=\})/, "gim");
str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
});

console.log(str);
```

I added (?<={) and (?=}) to the previous answer to have it only match occurrences where the key was within curly braces

Previous Answer - [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings)

Comment: I would try simply `/\{([^}]+)\}/` to match on any string surrounded by curly braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a capture group, and you'll get the value as the 2nd param of the replace callback:

```js
var str = "The {type} went to the {place}";

var mapObj = {
  type: 'Man',
  place: "Shop"

};

str = str.replace(/\{([^{}]+)\}/gim, function(_, c) {
  return mapObj[c.toLowerCase()] || `{${c}}`;
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: Given the nature of OP's question I would imagine there will be instances where a variable in the string does not have a match in the `mapObj`.

Comment: Something like `return mapObj[c.toLowerCase()] !== undefined ? mapObj[c.toLowerCase()] : '{'+c+'}';` would fix it.

Comment: That works perfectly, added the suggestion from @MonkeyZeus as there could be instances where a variable doesn't match a key within mapObj so better to return it as it was

Comment: @TamoorMalik I would suggest using the `return` statement from my comment because it would properly handle mismatched data types so that you could do something like `type: 0` reliably.