# Kotlin - Is there a base function to replace multiple strings with multiple strings in a reference String?

Tags: string, algorithm, kotlin, replace

Is there a base function or simple way to replace multiple strings with multiple strings in a reference String?

I have seen [Replace multiple strings with multiple other strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15604140/replace-multiple-strings-with-multiple-other-strings) but it is using known lists instead of variable ones.

For example:

I have `val str =  "THE GOAT IS RED"` , and I want to replace all the characters with other characters or digits, something like:

```
str.replace("THEGOAISRD".toList(), "0123456789".toList())
```

To which will result

```
"012 3450 67 829"
```

Comment: the result should actually be: 012 3470 56 829 doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
val list1 = listOf('a', 'b', 'c')
val list2 = listOf('0', '1', '2')
val str = "abacada"
val transform = list1.withIndex().associate { it.value to list2[it.index] }
val result = str.map { transform[it] ?: it }.joinToString(separator = "")
println(result)
```

prints `01020d0`

Comment: You could simplify it: `transform = list1.zip(list2).toMap()`. This even lets you skip the step of converting them to lists: `transform = "abc".zip("012").toMap()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that by first building a dictionary (`Map<Char, Char>`) using [`zip`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html) and then iterating the string to transform with [`joinToString`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/join-to-string.html) like that:

```
val str = "THE GOAT IS RED"

val dictionary = "THEGOAISRD".zip("0123475689").toMap()

val result = str.toCharArray().joinToString("") {
    dictionary.getOrDefault(it, it).toString()
}

println(result)
```