# How to render escaped html in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, escaping, innerhtml

I have a string response containing escaped HTML that I am trying to render inside a div using innerHTML. The table is not getting rendered. Instead i'm seeing the output as unescaped html with the table tags : `<table width=583px><tr><td>Sunshine</td><td>Unicorns</td></tr></table>`. Is there a work around for this?

In my test.component.ts,

```
public testStringWithEscape = '&lt;table width=583px&gt;&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;Sunshine&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;Unicorns&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;&lt;/table&gt;';
```

in test.component.html,

```
<div [innerHtml]="testStringWithEscape"></div>
```

**P.S:** I know that we have solution for this in javascript/angular JS. But  I'm specifically trying to understand if there is a way in Angular4/6/8.

Comment: You can replace the string to html tags [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15604206/11719787)

Comment: so, the api response is escaped html, and we need to render the response in application.

Comment: There are several ways to do this [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1912522/11719787), Just research before posting any question :)

Comment: I am looking for angular 6/8 specific solutions. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
    var e = document.createElement('div');
    e.innerHTML = input;
    return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

see [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/unescape-html-in-js/) for usage