# How to replace specific words in plain HTML with <A>-links using cheerio?

Tags: html, dom, cheerio, domparser

I want to replace certain words or word groups with corresponding `<a>`-elements that link to specific sub-pages.

Let's say, I have the following text as my DIV-body:

> The decentralized exchange Balancer is currently experiencing a
> compromise of its interface, believed to be a DNS attack. Users should check their wallet balance.

I want to do the following replacements:

1. "*Balancer*": `<a href="/tags/balancer">Balancer</a>`
2. "*decentralized exchange*": `<a href="/tags/decentralized-exchange">decentralized exchange</a>`
3. "*balance*": `<a href="/tags/balance">balance</a>`

So the final html should look like this:

```
The <a href="/tags/decentralized-echange">decentralized exchange<a/> <a href="/tags/balancer">Balancer</a> is currently experiencing a
compromise of its interface, believed to be a DNS attack. Users should check their wallet <a href="/tags/balance">balance</a>.
```

I can't use RegExp because this would replace the already replaced link to "Balancer" with another Link pointing to "Balance", which would make the first Balancer-link corrupt.

Using cheerio, I would be able to replace certain HTML elements with other elements like this:

```
let $ = cheerio.load(html)

$('.alt2 div:contains("Originally Posted by")')
  .replaceWith('<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</blockquote>')

console.log($.html())
```

However, in my case, I have flat text without any selectable nodes. But after the first replacement, the flat text body will contain the first node and then a second one, which needs to be not addressed with the replacement again.

For me it is not clear, how can I replace words in text nodes, that are not really nodes like in the example above?

How can I do this with?

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) as it's a very unusual set of requirements that smells hacky, and probably should be redesigned. Where is your HTML coming from? If you control it, the normal approach would be using EJS templates, for example. If there is a good reason for this, can you post all of your possible inputs? I'm not really clear when it's pure flat text and when it's pre-tagged, and what both of those might look like exactly. Thanks.

Comment: thx @ggorlen I get multiple articles from a CMS, which contains just pure plain text. And within this text, I want to replace certain keywords with deeplinks to subpages. I am not sure if this is really an XY problem as it can be seen across the globe on all blogs and news-sites. Isn't it?

Comment: If it contains pure text, then why the concern about replacing something twice? The XY issue isn't because CMS articles are common, it's that it's unusual to be so out of control of your source documents that you can't be sure whether it's already been processed or not. That begs one to inquire what you're really trying to achieve with all of this and suggests that there's usually a much simpler solution. Maybe there isn't, and Cheerio really is the best solution. It's hard to know one way or another without context.

Comment: If the text truly has no HTML in it, then Cheerio is the wrong tool, and a simple [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67374697/6243352) should be sufficient. Cheerio only helps when you have HTML tags, which it sounds like you may not here.

Comment: @ggorlen the regex is destroying my html once I replaced "Balancer" with the corresponding a-tag, followed by another replacement of "Balance" (single word) because then the HREF and A-text to "Balancer" will be affected as well. Thats why I need to cut out the existing anchor-elements from being replaced (they start to exist after the first replacement)

Comment: The link I provided does it all in one pass, so there's no issue of previous replacements affecting future replacements. I don't see any multiple-pass code shown though. Your pattern would be something like `/balancer|balance/g` with the longer substring first to ensure you don't do `<a href="...">balance</a>r`. Word boundaries can also help avoid this: `/\bbalance\b|\bbalancer\b/g`